# Double-bracket if-statement not working

Tags: bash

```
if [[ $nb_dd > 0 ]]; then
    INPUT_TYPE="txt"
fi

if [ $nb_dd > 0 ]; then
    INPUT_TYPE="txt"
fi
```

The first check (using double brackets) fails to execute, causing the script to exit upon error as `$INPUT_TYPE` is not populated - but the latter version (single bracket) works, correctly setting `$INPUT_TYPE`. Why is this?

I'm running on OS X (10.11.4) (`echo $SHELL = /bin/bash`) - this is from a widely distributed suite of tools which were presumingly built on a Linux platform - and the .sh script otherwise works for the author so it may be a platform-specific issue although I can't think why.

Comment: You are comparing the string `$nb_dd` to the string `0`

Comment: Note that the second fragment creates a file `0` and checks whether what's in `$nb_dd` matches some test expression after splitting.  If there's a single word in it, then it'll check that it is non-empty (which, at that stage, it will be).  The first is comparing whether the contents of `$nb_dd` is a numeric value and bigger than 0.  (You mention OS X 10.11.4 — is that a pre-release?  I thought I was up to date and I've only got 10.11.3.)

Comment: Do you realise that `fi` is missing from both your `if` statements, or is that a typo?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed - pre-release. Thanks for the explanation! Fully understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both "work" for me, however you are using the wrong type of test.  The `>` inside `[[` is doing a textual comparison.  For an arithmetic comparison either use the old `-gt` or (better) the correct brackets - double parentheses:

```
if (( nb_dd > 0 )); then
    INPUT_TYPE="txt"
fi
```

Note that the `$` is not used, since only numerics can be compared inside `((...))` (using a `$` inside might work but can give strange side-effects because of expansion order).

Comment: `$` will work fine; the shell simply peforms normal parameter expansion on the value before evaluating the arithmetic statement. If the variable isn't set, you'll get a syntax error for `(( > 0 ))` (which I actually prefer to silently treating the value as 0, but otherwise the behavior is the same.

Comment: @chepner:  You are right, I was thinking of calculations like `echo $(( a++)) ` vs `echo $(( $a++)) `

Comment: €cheapener: Also I note that the `$` is mandatory when testing `$#`.

Comment: Right; arithmetic expressions recursively expand *variables*, which are a distinct subset of all *parameters* (which include the positional parameters 1, 2, ... and the special parameters whose names are single, nonalphanumeric characters).

Answer (score 2):

You must `gt` and `lt` to make comparisons,

```
if [[ $nb_dd -gt 0 ]];
   then INPUT_TYPE="txt";
fi

if [ $nb_dd -gt 0 ];
   then INPUT_TYPE="txt";
fi
```

---

Double brackets just extend posix functionality

`>` means nothing in posix compliant `test` expressions, and it just calls the output redirection.

```
[ 2 > 3 ]   && echo "shouldn't print this"

[ 2 -gt 3 ] && echo "this isn't printed"
```

On extensions expressions to the posix ones it means sting comparison.

```
[[ "aa" > "ab" ]] && echo "doesn't print"
[[ "aa" > "aa" ]] && echo "doesn't print"
[[ "ab" > "aa" ]] && echo "prints"
```

Comment: `>` absolutely means something in a test expression. It is string comparison.

Comment: It turns you're right, only with `[[   ]]`, `>`  doesn't work with `test` or `[  ]` , editing my answer

Comment: Ah, true. It isn't POSIX but bash does support it in `test`/`[` but it looks like other shells don't. Though even there it "means something". It just happens to mean "output redirection".